# Query an elasticsearch index by an attribute, with a given range?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, time, range

I want to query my index so that it matches whenever a particular attribute shows up called sitename, but I want all the data from a certain time range. I thought it might be something of the below but unsure:

```
  {
      "query": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-1h/h",
            "lt": "now/h"
          }
        },
        "match": {"sitename" : "HARB00ZAF0" } 
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, but you need to leverage the [`bool` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-1h/h",
              "lt": "now/h"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "sitename": "HARB00ZAF0"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it worked! Thank you so much, i was so stuck on this and it seemed so simple. thank you again!